How do I distinguish a user hitting Ctrl-c vs EOF using Deno's prompt function?
Let's say I have a simple program like this:
while (true) {
  const command = prompt('Enter something');
  if (!command) {
    Deno.exit(0);
  }
}

What I want to do is replicate bash's behavior where:

Hitting Ctrl-d exits the process
Hitting Ctrl-c is effectively just a continue so it goes to the next iteration of the loop

But it looks like by default the prompt function returns null in either case. Since the signal handler is async, I can't see how I'd use one to distinguish whether the input was Ctrl-c vs Ctrl-d. Is there another way to do this?

^ If that answers your question, I can write it as one. If not, what did I miss?

Yes, that answers my question

^ @FinleyBaker Ok — done

There is actually a workaround for this behavior though it's a bit obtuse. I think the issue is that the signal comes in while the prompt is waiting for user input. We can overcome this obstacle by using a promise and setTimeout:
let sigint = false;
Deno.addSignalListener("SIGINT", () => {
  sigint = true;
});

// Add a timeout to prevent process exiting immediately.
while (true) {
  const val = prompt("Prompt: ");
  const printHandlerPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(val);
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (sigint) {
        console.log('sigint!');
        sigint = false;
      }
      resolve(null);
    }, 0);
  });
  await printHandlerPromise;
}


Because Deno's implementation of prompt emits the interrupt signal (SIGINT) when the user presses the Escape key (sources prompt, op_read_line_prompt), there is no way to discriminate whether the signal was generated by the user or on behalf of the user. Therefore you'll have to use a different input capturing mechanism than the global prompt function.

So it turns out that there actually is a workaround for this that I point out in my answer, though it's a bit complicated. I filed a bug to see if there's a better possible behavior.
